# Failed to load qt platform plugin "windows"; already included it but still not working

Tags: qt

I'm trying to do a shared compilation for my project and have included all necessary .dlls. I get this error telling me that the "windows" plugin could not be located, when I have already included that also, in the platforms folder.
If anyone could help, that'd be great because I'm going crazy.

Comment: You need to add some others dlls, not only plugins\qwindows.dll. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368826/deploying-qt-c-application-from-visual-studio-qwindows-dll-error . The easiest way is to use the standard Qt's util **windeployqt**

Comment: Using **windeployqt** - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22185974/deploying-qt-5-app-on-windows/22217114#22217114

Comment: Wow I had no idea windeployqt existed! this makes my life so much easier, thank you, legend!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt5 Static Build yields Failed to load platform plugin "windows"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773789/qt5-static-build-yields-failed-to-load-platform-plugin-windows)