# How to step into Qt source code in QT Creator with Qt 5.14 MSVC2017?

Tags: c++, debugging, qt5, qt-creator

I want to step into Qt source code to see how some of its functions work. But I can't step into the Qt source code.

What I've tried:

- Tools - Options - Debugger - General - Add Qt sources... - select Qt source folder (`D:\Qt\Qt5.14.1\5.14.1\Src`, which is installed along with installation of Qt 5.14.1)
- Tools - Options - Debugger - CDB Paths - Insert Symbol Server... - click OK with default value.
- new project with code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QLabel l;
    l.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

- add breakpoint at `l.show()`.
- start debugging

and still can't step into the Qt function `QLabel::show()`.

What had I missed ?

Thanks a lot.

---

Environment:
*Windows 10

Qt 5.14.1 with MSVC 2017

Microsoft Visual Studio 2019*

Comment: I think you mean that a window pops-up asking where to look for `QLabel.h` the first time, and every time after VS pops-up a tab saying "Source Not Found"? I have this problem too, but I'm able to compile and run all my projects (in Debug mode), [not in release Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62559840/how-to-solve-the-no-qt-platform-plugin-could-be-initialized-problem). Just for curiosity: are you able to run  a template in release mode? Thanks.

Comment: @BlayerBond  Sure, It compiles both in debug mode and release mode. I just want to see underneath the Qt source.

Comment: hm that's sad. I hoped the _no-release_ problem and the _source-not-found_ problem were linked together, so a more common solution was needed.